# Python keypress event detection using keyboard module

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-events

I used keyboard module to implement a keypress event detector for a code. I need to detect the keypress event inside a `while` loop inside a `for` loop. The code is as follows

```
import keyboard

for i in range(5):
    loop = True
    while loop:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
            print("Iteration: {}\tSpace key pressed!".format(i))
            loop = False
```

The output shows after pressing `space` key once:

```
Iteration: 0    Space key pressed!
Iteration: 1    Space key pressed!
Iteration: 2    Space key pressed!
Iteration: 3    Space key pressed!
Iteration: 4    Space key pressed!
```

I want it to detect only when the key is pressed. `is_pressed` sets it to true forever once the key is pressed. Is there any other way to get it detected only once and reset the `is_pressed` to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import keyboard
import time

yes = 1
delay = 0.2 # or >= 0.2 secs works fine

for i in range(5):
    loop = True
    while loop:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
            if yes = 1:
                yes = 0
                print("Iteration: {}\tSpace key pressed!".format(i))
                loop = False
        else:
            yes = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code works if you introduce some delay, of ~0.2 secs, between each check of key being pressed.

```
import keyboard
import time

delay = 0.2 # or >= 0.2 secs works fine

for i in range(5):
    loop = True
    while loop:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
            print("Iteration: {}\tSpace key pressed!".format(i))
            loop = False
            time.sleep(delay) # adding delay between each checks
```

Comment: It worked for me even with a delay of `0.1`.